# Is “ing” needed here? “I felt busy than work(ing) from home”

Tags: comparative-constructions

May I know which sentences is correct?

- I am working from home but with my kids at home, I felt busy than working from office.
- I am working from home but with my kids at home, I felt busy than work from office.

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. Please note that this is neither a proofreading service nor a writers' workshop, and requests for corrections or choosing the "right" sentence are not accepted here. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of "working" versus "work", it should be "working".

Also, "office" would idiomatically take the definite article "the".

And as you are making a comparison, it should be "I felt **busier** than working from the office".

Comment: Or "I felt busier than I did [when] working from/at the office".

Answer (score 1):

The sentence has more than one error.

- The correct sentence is given below :

> I am working from home, but, with my kids at home, I feel busier than I felt while working from my office.

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted. The one improvement to this answer would be to say what exactly was with the original sentence. It would probably help the OP's understanding.